# Append value of an XML Element with additional text using regular expressions

Tags: regex, xml, c#-4.0, rdl

I am trying to convert the following in an XML

```
<SharedDataSetReference>AnyDataSetName</SharedDataSetReference>
```

to

```
<SharedDataSetReference>/DataSets/AnyDataSetName</SharedDataSetReference>
```

at the same time, existing instances of

```
<SharedDataSetReference>/DataSets/AnyDataSetName</SharedDataSetReference>
```

should remain unchanged.

Pls note that AnyDataSetName can have

```
<SharedDataSetReference>Company</SharedDataSetReference>
<SharedDataSetReference>Customer</SharedDataSetReference>
```

or
    /Datasets/Order

and they should change to

```
<SharedDataSetReference>/Datasets/Company</SharedDataSetReference>
<SharedDataSetReference>/Datasets/Customer</SharedDataSetReference>
<SharedDataSetReference>/Datasets/Order</SharedDataSetReference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<SharedDataSetReference>([^\/]+)<\/SharedDataSetReference>
```

https://regex101.com/r/yM7tA0/1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim007
This is what i did

```
var sharedDatasets = Regex.Replace(datasets.First().ToString(), String.Format(@"<{0}>(?<DataSetReferenceValue>[^\/]+)<\/{0}>", "SharedDataSetReference"), delegate(Match match)
            {
                var value = String.Concat("/Datasets/", match.Groups["DataSetReferenceValue"].ToString());
                return String.Format(@"<{0}>{1}</{0}>", "SharedDataSetReference", value);
            }, RegexOptions.Multiline
            )
```